# SOQL query with carriage return in field

Tags: soql

I'm trying to issue a SOQL query where one of the WHERE clauses is for a filed that contains a carriage return.  The following query doesn't work.  I've tried \r, \n\r, \r\n and \n, but none of them work.  The Street field doesn't always include a carriage return.  If I remove the match on Street__c, the query works fine.  How should I handle this?

```
SELECT Id FROM AccountLocation__c WHERE AccountId__c = '001M000000tYp9GIAS' and Street__c = '33400 7 MILE RD\nSuite 101' and City__c = 'LIVONIA' and State__c = 'MI' and PostalCode__c LIKE '48152-4909%'
```

UPDATE

The following did not work either:

```
SELECT Id FROM AccountLocation__c WHERE AccountId__c = '001M000000tYp9GIAS' and Street__c LIKE '33400 7 MILE RD%Suite 101' and City__c = 'LIVONIA' and State__c = 'MI' and PostalCode__c LIKE '48152-4909%'
```

Comment: You could use the like wildcard character `%` that matches zero or more of any character (so isn;t exactly what you want put probably good enough): `Street__c like '33400 7 MILE RD%Suite 101'`.

Comment: `LIKE` query is a lot less efficient though...and also doesn't make sense in your postal code filter.

Comment: @KeithC Let me try that out

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, the extra LIKE for the zip code is extraneous.  Its something I should remove, certainly.

Comment: It might also be worth just splitting out `Street Line 1` and `Street Line 2` into separate fields using trigger/wfr/pb/formula, whatever's easiest for you.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Its already a pretty specific query given that it has `AccountId__c = '001M000000tYp9GIAS'`.

Comment: Yeah, it may be overly specific. Also probably should remove the hard-coded id...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Unfortunately, I can't split out the fields at this point.  The app has been in production for over a year now.

Comment: @KeithC  I'm trying to find one AccountLocation record where the AccountId matches and the rest of the address fields match.  One Account has multiple account locations.  That is why I'm matching on all of those fields.  Just matching on the AccountId would not be enough.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This is just an example of the query that is failing.  The code itself is building the query dynamically.  There no actual hard-coded IDs in use.

Comment: Adding those two fields would be purely additive, especially if you get it working with formulas. Is post-processing via `Apex` an option?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Currently the SOQL query is being run via JavaScript.  When you say "post-processing", do you mean getting all the records that are LIKE the part of the street address up to the carriage return, then doing a match each record returned to see which one exactly matches the street address?

Comment: Right. Remove the query filter (just for that field) and loop through the candidate results to see if any are an exact match. Just a thought.

Comment: I can do that.  Seems like a hack.  I can't believe we can't query on fields with a value that contains a carriage return.